# PHP: Displaying the lists for each div

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have multiple divs that look like the HTML Below. For each of these divs, Im trying to get the Input values via the name LI_Dept as an array. These are posted through PHP.

How do i get the list or input values for each of these divs rather than displaying all the lists of all the divs. If that makes sense?

The Problem is to do with my PHP code regarding the `foreach($list as $li){}`, anyone have any ideas?

Thanks

**HTML**

```
<div id="table_dept" class="count">
  <span class="dept_format">
    TEST
  </span>
  <input id="ID_Dept" name="ID_Dept[]" type="text" class="dept_textfields" value="1" maxlength="3">
  <span class="dept_format">
    TEST1
  </span>
  <input id="deptcode_Dept" name="DC_Dept[]" type="text" class="dept_textfields" value="2" maxlength="30">
  <span class="dept_format">
    TEST2
  </span>
  <input id="deptname_Dept" name="DN_Dept[]" type="text" class="dept_textfields" value="2" maxlength="50">
  <span class="dept_format">
    List:
  </span>
  <table width="100%">
    <thead>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="D_tbody">
      <tr>
      </tr>
      <tr>
      </tr>
      <tr>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input id="list_Dept" name="LI_Dept[]" type="text" class="dept_li_textfields" value="List1" maxlength="50">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input id="list_Dept" name="LI_Dept[]" type="text" class="dept_li_textfields" value="List2" maxlength="50">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input id="list_Dept" name="LI_Dept[]" type="text" class="dept_li_textfields" value="List3" maxlength="50">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input id="list_Dept" name="LI_Dept[]" type="text" class="dept_li_textfields" value="List4" maxlength="50">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input id="list_Dept" name="LI_Dept[]" type="text" class="dept_li_textfields" value="List5" maxlength="50">
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

**PHP:**

```
for($i=0;$i < $rowcount;$i++)  <---FOR EACH DIV
{
    $dID = $_POST['ID_Dept'];
    $dDCode = $_POST['DC_Dept'];
    $dName = $_POST['DN_Dept'];
    $list= $_POST['LI_Dept'];   

    foreach ($list as $li) {   <-----I Need HELP to change this for EACH DIV RATHER THAN ALL...
        $Acontent .= "\r\n".'<'.$element_LI.'>'.$li.'</'.$element_LI.'>';
    }
}
```

**Result:**
My current result, NOT WHAT I AM AFTER.

```
<Department id="1">
<DeptCode>1</DeptCode>
<DeptName>1</DeptName>
<li>List1</li>
<li>List2</li>
<li>List3</li>
<li>List4</li>
<li>List5</li>
<li>List6</li>
<li>List7</li>
<li>List8</li>
<li>List9</li>
<li>List10</li>
<li>List11</li>
<li>List12</li>
<li>List13</li>
<li>List14</li>
<li>List15</li>
<li>List16</li>

<Department id="2">
<DeptCode>2</DeptCode>
<DeptName>2</DeptName>
<li>List1</li>
<li>List2</li>
<li>List3</li>
<li>List4</li>
<li>List5</li>
<li>List6</li>
<li>List7</li>
<li>List8</li>
<li>List9</li>
<li>List10</li>
<li>List11</li>
<li>List12</li>
<li>List13</li>
<li>List14</li>
<li>List15</li>
<li>List16</li>

<Department id="3">
<DeptCode>3</DeptCode>
<DeptName>3</DeptName>
<li>List1</li>
<li>List2</li>
<li>List3</li>
<li>List4</li>
<li>List5</li>
<li>List6</li>
<li>List7</li>
<li>List8</li>
<li>List9</li>
<li>List10</li>
<li>List11</li>
<li>List12</li>
<li>List13</li>
<li>List14</li>
<li>List15</li>
<li>List16</li>
```

**Requirement**
The below structure is what i am trying to achieve, rather than the above,using PHP.

```
<Department id="1">
<DeptCode>1</DeptCode>
<DeptName>1</DeptName>
<li>List1</li>
<li>List2</li>
<li>List3</li>
<li>List4</li>
<li>List5</li>
<li>List6</li>

<Department id="2">
<DeptCode>2</DeptCode>
<DeptName>2</DeptName>
<li>List7</li>
<li>List8</li>
<li>List9</li>
<li>List10</li>
<li>List11</li>

<Department id="3">
<DeptCode>3</DeptCode>
<DeptName>3</DeptName>
<li>List12</li>
<li>List13</li>
<li>List14</li>
<li>List15</li>
<li>List16</li>
```

Comment: Don't quit understand your question, This code seems to do what you're asking `for($i=0;$i < $rowcount;$i++)
{
$dID = $_POST['ID_Dept'];
$dDCode = $_POST['DC_Dept'];
$dName = $_POST['DN_Dept'];
$list= $_POST['LI_Dept']; }`

Comment: What determines how your lists get broken up? Like the one has 6 dropdowns and the other have 5. What determines those breaks?

Comment: Thats what im trying to figure out in PHP. I need them to be broken up depending on each div. Look at my Requirement, I am trying to make my output look like the requirement rather than the result. If that makes sense. I am trying to figure out how to break the lists using PHP and output them as an ECHO or something rather than showing all the li tags FOR EACH DIV.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT 
list1 as l1, list2 as l2, list3 as l3, list4 as l4, list5 as l5, list6 as l6, 1 AS selection
WHERE x = y

UNION ALL 

SELECT 
list7 as l1, list8 as l2, list9 as l3, list10 as l4, list11 as l5, list12 as l6, 2 AS selection 
WHERE x = y
) 
as request

$reponse->execute(); 

for($i=0;$data = $reponse->fetch();$i++)
{
<Department id="<?php echo $data['selection'] ?>">
<DeptCode><?php echo $data['selection'] ?></DeptCode>
<DeptName><?php echo $data['selection'] ?></DeptName>
<li><?php echo $data['l1'] ?></li>
<li><?php echo $data['l2'] ?></li>
<li><?php echo $data['l3'] ?></li>
<li><?php echo $data['l4'] ?></li>
<li><?php echo $data['l5'] ?></li>
<li><?php echo $data['l6'] ?></li>

}
```

Comment: This isn't quite what im after, thanks for giving it a go.

FOR EACH DIV:
   ECHO ID
   ECHO DEPTNAME
   ECHO DEPTCODE
  FOR EACH LIST (LI) INSIDE CURRENT DIV:
     ECHO THE LIST.

Dont know if that PSUEDO CODE will help to explain it...